# How to print Full NSMutable request

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsmutableurlrequest

I am creating a `NSMutableRequest` like this

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *postData = [postParam dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postParam length]];

//[request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

Now I want to check what is the full url passing to the service from my app. Because seems my url has some issue. I want to see the full request to see, not just the url and binded parameters seperately. 
How can I do this?
Please help me. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're sending a POST request. Therefore, adding parameters will not change the URL.

I suggest you use a proxy like `Charles` or `Fiddler` and route the traffic via them. You can see basically everything you need related to `http`.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the log like this,

```
NSLog(@"URL=%@ %@", request.URL, postParam);
```

You will get the url with params.